# add a red border on a cell which has failed the validation in mui

Tags: validation, error-handling, material-ui

I am new with mui and I have added the validation using the code below :

```
   const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'firstName',
    preProcessEditCellProps: (params: GridPreProcessEditCellProps) => {
      const hasError = params.props.value.length < 3;
      return { ...params.props, error: hasError };
    },
  },
];
```

my question how can I highlight the cell with a a red border ? so the person can know which cell is having a problem ?

Comment: i found the solution here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/recipes-editing/#conditional-validation